# Solr result is not highlighting on a particular word

Tags: solr

We are using solr in our application as a search engine.
And for highlighting we are depending on solr result.

Query passed to solr for highlighting

```
hl.q=AddressLine1%3a(Puthanmadhom)+PartyNameBusiness%3a(Puthanmadhom)+AddressState%3a(All)+&q.op=OR&hl=true&hl.fl=*&hl.requireFieldMatch=true&hl.simple.pre=%3cb%3e&hl.simple.post=%3c%2fb%3e
```

Here the word "Puthanmadhom", is not highlighted in the solr results. But almost all other words are working fine. Even "Puthanmad" is highlighting properly.

Any possible reason of failure are welcome.

Thanks,
Varun

Comment: Are you saying this query works? hl.q=AddressLine1%3a(Puthanmad)+PartyNameBusiness%3a(Puthanmad)+AddressState%3a(All)+&q.op=OR&hl=true&hl.fl=*&hl.requireFieldMatch=true&hl.simple.pre=%3cb%3e&hl.simple.post=%3c%2fb%3e

Comment: Exactly. if I remove "hom", highlighting is happening.

Comment: Possibly related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12232302/802117

Answer (score 1):

```
hl.q=AddressLine1%3a(Puthanmadhom)+PartyNameBusiness%3a(Puthanmadhom)+AddressState%3a(All)+&q.op=OR&hl=true&hl.fl=*&hl.requireFieldMatch=true&hl.simple.pre=%3cb%3e&hl.simple.post=%3c%2fb%3e
```

This query string is broken by an extra space, after "...(All)+&q.op...". Change to "...(All)&q.op..." and it should work.

Comment: Removed extra '+', still no change in result.

Comment: I would expect that a standard solr query for those terms also yields no results. Is that true?